# Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have written webhook functions in the inline editor.
I get the deadline exceeded error intermittently.
All webhooks which failed with deadline exceeded error has webhook_latency_ms : 4992ms
In Dialogflow documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how) it's mentioned that default timeout is 5sec, as per this my webhook should not throw this error because it's within 5sec.

The webhook has a very simple code that will take no more than 20-30ms.
Most of the time, the same function has webhook_latency_ms: less than 50ms. 
What are the factors that could contribute to increased latency?

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
function testHandler(agent) { 
    let pendingHabits = agent.getContext('pendinghabits').parameters.habits; 
    let message = "Ok, let me know when you complete these habits:"; 
    for (let i = 0; i < pendingHabits.length; i++) { 
        message = message + "\n" + pendingHabits[i]; 
    } 
    let payload = { 
        type: 'message', 
        isPositive: false, 
        messages: [{ type: 0, text: message }] 
    }; 
    agent.add(new Payload(agent.UNSPECIFIED, payload)); 
}})
```

Comment: can you update with code

Comment: Also the firebase log says Function execution took 1911 ms, finished with status code: 200 and webhook latency is 4992ms. It's quite confusing.

Comment: please update in question its not readble

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your handler call, as i can see the code you have provided,

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient, Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ req, res });

  function intentHandler(agent) {
    agent.add('This message is from Dialogflow\'s Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!');
    agent.add(new Card({
        title: 'Title: this is a card title',
        imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant.png',
        text: 'This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! ',
        buttonText: 'This is a button',
        buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
      })
    );
    agent.add(new Suggestion('Quick Reply'));
    agent.add(new Suggestion('Suggestion'));
  }

  agent.handleRequest(intentHandler);
});
```